# New Copied Array Is Also Affecting Old Original Array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, copy

```
const array = [
{
  username: "name",
  password: "pass"
},
{
  username: "name",
  password: "pass"
},
{
  username: "name",
  password: "pass"
},
{
  username: "name",
  password: "pass"
},
];

const newArray = array.slice();

for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
  newArray[i].username = newArray[i].username + "!";
};
```

Hello, I cannot figure out why `.slice()` is not working for me. When I run through the for loop to add "!" to the usernames and save the new usernames into the `newArray`, the original array is also having "!" added to the usernames. I looked up another answer on here and the code worked perfectly, and the original array was unaffected. I don't see what's going wrong here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the objects are being passed by reference.

Try this

```
const newArray = array.map(({ username, password }) => {
  return {
    password,
    username: username + "!"
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Using map to accomplish it is part 2 of the question actually, for part 1 I was supposed to use forEach but couldn't figure it out so I tried a basic for loop. I'll check out what passing objects through reference means and see if that will help me figure out part one. Thank you!